# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\;\frac{ 1+ \frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{ (\pi^n + e^n)^{1/n} \ln{n} }$

Tags: limits

I have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\;\frac{ 1+ \frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{ (\pi^n + e^n)^{1/n} \ln{n} }$$
How should I proceed? Is there a way to use integration as limit of a sum here?

Comment: Have you tried Stolz-Cesaro:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem ?

Comment: I’m not aware of this theorem. :|

Comment: That theorem proceeds derivatives which proceed integrals, so you should start from the beginning. I don't know what your idea was, but the harmonic series in the numerator diverges.

Comment: Use $1 + \frac{1}{2} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{n} = \ln n + \mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: I would write: $\pi\left(1+\left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\pi^n+e^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \pi \left[1+\left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^n\right]^{\frac{1}{n}} = \pi$$

since $\pi > e$. So the limit equals:

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln n} \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots +\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Intuitively the inner limit should be one because $H_n \sim \ln n + \gamma$, but we can also prove it with Cesaro-Stolz:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln n} \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots +\frac{1}{n}\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1} \ln\frac{n}{n+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{\ln e} = 1$$

The final result is $\dfrac{1}{\pi}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$1+ \frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ is an upper Riemann sum for the integral $\;\int_1^{n+1}\frac {\mathrm d x}x=\ln(n+1)\;$ and $\;\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\;$  is a lower Riemann sum for the integral $\;\int_1^n \frac {\mathrm d x}x=\ln n$, so
$$\frac{\ln(n+1)}{ (\pi^n + e^n)^{1/n} \ln{n}}\le \frac{ 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}{(\pi^n + e^n)^{1/n} \ln{n}}\le\frac{1+\ln n}{ (\pi^n + e^n)^{1/n} \ln{n}}.$$
Now $\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln{n}}$ and $\frac{1+\ln n}{\ln{n}}$ both tend to $1$ as $n\to\infty$, so there remains to find
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(\pi^n + e^n)^{1/n}}.$$